# Cannot seem to restart Elastic Search without red status

Tags: elasticsearch

whenever I restart my one and only Elastic Search node I keep just getting the red status and having to delete my data directory and lose all my data...

Here is the log from a restart of the node:

```
[2013-12-22 12:44:24,257][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] version[0.90.8], pid[1494], build[909b037/2013-12-18T16:08:16Z]
[2013-12-22 12:44:24,257][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] initializing ...
[2013-12-22 12:44:24,265][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Dominic Fortune] loaded [], sites [HQ, head]
[2013-12-22 12:44:26,818][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] initialized
[2013-12-22 12:44:26,818][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] starting ...
[2013-12-22 12:44:26,891][INFO ][transport                ] [Dominic Fortune] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.183.128:9300]}
[2013-12-22 12:44:29,919][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Dominic Fortune] new_master [Dominic Fortune][5ddMpkRQTZa3TqQ-ljUabg][inet[/192.168.183.128:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2013-12-22 12:44:29,951][INFO ][discovery                ] [Dominic Fortune] elasticsearch/5ddMpkRQTZa3TqQ-ljUabg
[2013-12-22 12:44:29,979][INFO ][http                     ] [Dominic Fortune] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.183.128:9200]}
[2013-12-22 12:44:29,980][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] started
[2013-12-22 12:44:29,987][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Dominic Fortune] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2013-12-22 12:45:07,323][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Dominic Fortune] [main] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[2], mappings []
[2013-12-22 12:45:17,669][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Dominic Fortune] [main] create_mapping [_default_]
[2013-12-22 12:45:17,680][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Dominic Fortune] [main] create_mapping [help]
[2013-12-22 12:47:19,818][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] stopping ...
[2013-12-22 12:47:19,845][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] stopped
[2013-12-22 12:47:19,845][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] closing ...
[2013-12-22 12:47:19,856][INFO ][node                     ] [Dominic Fortune] closed
[2013-12-22 12:47:45,495][INFO ][node                     ] [Stryker, William] version[0.90.8], pid[1695], build[909b037/2013-12-18T16:08:16Z]
[2013-12-22 12:47:45,496][INFO ][node                     ] [Stryker, William] initializing ...
[2013-12-22 12:47:45,502][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Stryker, William] loaded [], sites [HQ, head]
[2013-12-22 12:47:48,068][INFO ][node                     ] [Stryker, William] initialized
[2013-12-22 12:47:48,068][INFO ][node                     ] [Stryker, William] starting ...
[2013-12-22 12:47:48,140][INFO ][transport                ] [Stryker, William] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.183.128:9300]}
[2013-12-22 12:47:51,170][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Stryker, William] new_master [Stryker, William][rMklMXasRDS4lURA0wQ7lQ][inet[/192.168.183.128:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2013-12-22 12:47:51,198][INFO ][discovery                ] [Stryker, William] elasticsearch/rMklMXasRDS4lURA0wQ7lQ
[2013-12-22 12:47:51,222][INFO ][http                     ] [Stryker, William] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.183.128:9200]}
[2013-12-22 12:47:51,223][INFO ][node                     ] [Stryker, William] started
[2013-12-22 12:47:51,242][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Stryker, William] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
```

As you can see `Dominic Fortune` downs and then `Stryker, William` comes online after the node restart. There are no other nodes, the status on my cluster from the HQ plugin says 1 node.

Despite this I cannot stop my cluster from going into red status whenever I do this.

How can I fix a problem I cannot see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I actually have been able to trial and error a fix.

The problem is that there was no data in the indexes when I restarted the node.

For some odd reason this makes Elastic Search explode as though it cannot find all the documents when in fact there are no documents to be found.

#### Edit

After posting on the Google Group I found this to be my stupidity, since I used a replica setting of 2 the quorum was expecting more than one node online.

When there wasn't due to lack of data etc it would fail and not recover the index to be used on the restart of Elastic Search.

Dumbo me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally **RED/Yellow** statuses(after a restart) occur if the shutdown is not done properly,
do not `cntrl + c` to stop elastic search, use a rest call mentioned [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-shutdown.html)

In dev mode I generally use

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/_master/_shutdown'
```

Mainly yellow status is due to some shards that are not allocated. If your cluster is in recovery status, just wait if there is enough space in nodes for your shards.
If your cluster, even after recovery is still in yellow state, it means you don't have enough nodes to contain your replicas so you can either reduce the number of your replicas or add the required number of nodes.

The total number of nodes must not be lower than the maximum number of replicas.