# elasticsearch: All primary shards become inactive when restart a single node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I started a new elasticsearch cluster and added a new index, then I shut it down.
When I try to start it again there is no active shards any more. All the shards became inactive and unassigned.
I use this index settings below:

```
"settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 32,
            "number_of_replicas": 3
        }
```

Here is health output:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "sailcraft",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 128,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0
}
```

Here is the [same problem which has been marked solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729704/cannot-seem-to-restart-elastic-search-without-red-status?answertab=active#tab-top). But I don't think that's the solution.

EDIT:

It's the same question but I think that post does not get the right answer. It said that we need 2 more nodes if we have 2 more replica shards. I read all the related docs and there is not any such restrictions.

EDIT2:
**Solution:
he setting index.recovery.initial_shards provides the following:
Basically, when using a local gateway, a "shard" will be recovered once a quorum of its copies are found among the nodes in the cluster.
Lets take N shard, with 1 replica (2 copies for each shard). The default (quorum) means that once a singe copy of a shard is found, it will be recovered. If you have 2 replicas (3 copies), it will only recover that shard once 2 copies are found.
You can set this setting, in case you lost a large number of nodes, and quorum is a too strict setting. You can actually set it on a "live" index (which is in a "red" state, obviously, because not all shards are recovered).**

Comment: The link you provided is the reason for the `red` status in your case.

Comment: It's the same question but I think that post dose not get the right answer. It said that we need 2 more nodes if we have 2 more replica shards. I read all the related docs and there is not any such restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) mentioning this. Indeed, it's not evident, but it's there:

> `index.recovery.initial_shards`
>
> When using local gateway a particular shard is recovered only if there can be allocated quorum shards in the cluster. It can be set to:
>
> quorum (default)
>
> quorum-1 (or half)
>
> full
>
> full-1.
>
> Number values are also supported, e.g. 1.

If you really want to have your node running, set `index.recovery.initial_shards: 1` in `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks so much. Follow your post I totally solved this problem.